# Central Administration, FBA, and the People Picker

Tags: 2010, forms-authentication, central-administration, people-picker

I have a web application using Windows Authentication, which is extended with Forms Based Authentication. That's all fine and dandy. The problem is I can't get the people picker to pull my FBA users in Central Administration.

I have the `<PeoplePickerWildcards>` set up properly:

```
<PeoplePickerWildcards>
  <clear />
  <add key="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" value="%" />
    <add key="FBAMembershipProvider" value="%"/>
</PeoplePickerWildcards>
```

The `<membership>` and the `<roleManager>` are set up as such:

```
<roleManager>
  <providers>
            <add name="FBARoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, 
                       System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
                       PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" applicationName="/" 
                       connectionStringName="FBADB" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership>
  <providers>
            <add name="FBAMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.
                       SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
                       PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" applicationName="/" 
                       connectionStringName="FBADB" enablePasswordReset="true" 
                       enablePasswordRetrieval="false" passwordFormat="Hashed"
                       requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

and the `<connectionStrings>` node:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add connectionString="blah blah blah" name="FBADB" />
</connectionStrings>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Am also facing the same issue, in MY SP 2010 web appln. Though I have done the exact thing as you followed, am also not getting the fba users in the peoplepicker. i want to add the fba user as site collec,.admin,but none of them loaded/recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the cause of this. The Central Administration web application was running as the farm account, which I had not added into the SQL permissions on the FBA user / role database.

Granting the farm account access resolved this issue.

I determined the account the web application was running as by navigating (in CA) to Security > Configure Service Accounts > Choose Farm Account in the dropdown (see image below).

[image: Farm Account]

Comment: I don't know that switching CA to Claims is even supported, but you don't need to.  Did you give the account running Central Admin read access to your SQL user database?  The account that runs CA *should* be different then the account running the pools of your Web App(s).

Comment: I based that on some bad advice I received. I have it up and running in my test environment, and the people picker works there. I'm going to hop on the other machine and figure out what I did wrong and fix this post.